# Ember tests cause TypeError: Cannot read property 'notFound' of null

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When writing my latest integration test, I suddenly find myself getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'notFound' of null`.

This seems to coincide with a `GET` request to `/my_model/:id/tests/index.html` which, of course, 404s.

Has anyone encountered this before? Any idea what may be happening or a starting point for debugging?

Comment: I've noticed Ember many times has error messages which themselves cause failures.  This message is a classic sign of that.  Can you find the corresponding source code and look at what Ember is trying to do here?  Then look at the Error message they wanted to print, and that may give you some clues.  Also, I wonder if "notFound" is a property it's expecting in response to an `HTTP 404` response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very compelling answer, but I was running on `0.1` of `ember-cli-pretender` and upgrading to `0.2.x` made this issue disappear.